# Encoding problem with bibliography in tufte class

Tags: bibliographies, font-encodings, tufte

I try to make a bibliography using tufte book style. As you see, the bibliography reference on the margins is all messed up.

[image]

I hope you understand, these weird *margin* symbols are not Russian, but the text is. I feel the problem is with an encoding (that is why the example is language oriented), but I don't understand why.

How to fix margin text into normal language, uploaded by babel-package? How to translate the word "and" automatically inserted by tufte-class for several citations? (boxed on the picture)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

Этот вопрос волнует обучающих\cite{Poya} и
обучающихся\cite{Gabovich, GPY} с момента возникновения самих задач. 

\backmatter
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

Output - see above.

The bibliography looks fine:
[image]

No problems with compilation. `Bibliography.bib` is a modification of `sample-handout.bib` provided by Tufte.

```
@BOOK{Sharygin,
    author = {И. Ф. Шарыгин},
    title = {Геометрия 10--11. Учебник для общеобразоватлеьных учебных заведений},
    year = {1999},
    publisher = {Дрофа},
    address = {Москва}
}

@BOOK{Sharygin500,
    author = {И. Ф. Шарыгин},
    title = {500 задач геометрического стандарта},
    publisher = {Просвещение},
    year = {2007},
    address = {Москва}
}

@BOOK{Sharygin10,
    author = {И. Ф. Шарыгин},
    title = {Факультативный курс по математике. Решение задач. Учебное пособие для 10 класса средней школы},
    publisher = {Просвещение},
    year = {1989},
    address = {Москва}
}

@BOOK{Sharygin11,
    author = {И. Ф. Шарыгин, В. И. Голубев},
    title = {Факультативный курс по
    математике. Решение задач. Учебное пособие для 11 класса средней школы},
    publisher = {Просвещение},
    year = {1991},
    address = {Москва}
}

@BOOK{Gabovich,
    author = {И. Г. Габович},
    title = {Алгоритмический подход к решению геометрических задач},
    publisher = {Просвещение},
    year = {1996},
    address = {Москва}
}

@BOOK{GPY,
    author = {В. Б. Полонский, Е. М. Рабинович, М. С. Якир},
    title = {Учимся решать задачи по геометрии},
    publisher = {Магiстр-S},
    year = {1996},
    address = {Киев}
}

@BOOK{Poya,
    author = {Г. Пойя},
    title = {Как решать задачу?},
    publisher = {Квантор},
    year = {1992},
    address = {Львов}
}

@BOOK{Zel,
    author = {О. П. Зеленяк},
    title = {Решение задач по планиметрии.Технология алгоритмического подхода на основе задач--теорем},
    publisher = {ДМК, Диасофт},
    year = {2008},
    address = {Киев}
}

@BOOK{GGK,
    author = {И. М. Гельфанд, Е. Г. Глаголева, А. А. Кириллов},
    title = {Метод координат},
    publisher = {Наука},
    year = {1973},
    address = {Москва}
}

@BOOK{Kushnir,
    author = {И. А. Кушнир},
    title = {Векторные методы решения задач},
    publisher = {Обериг},
    year = {1994},
    address = {Киев}
}

@BOOK{KushnirGB,
    author = {И. А. Кушнир},
    title = {Геометрия на баррикидах},
    publisher = {Факт},
    year = {2009},
    address = {Киев}
}

@BOOK{Kiselev,
    author = {А. П. Киселёв},
    title = {Геометрия. Планиметрия.
    Стереометрия. Учебник},
    publisher = {Физматлит},
    year = {2004},
    address = {Москва}
}

@BOOK{Prasolov,
    author = {В. В. Прасолов},
    title = {Задачи по стереометрии},
    publisher = {МЦНМО},
    year = {2010},
    address = {Москва}
}
```

Comment: `plainnat` is an english style. *`and`* is english.

Comment: I know that.  What to do in another language?

Comment: You need a russian style. Or use the more modern package `biblatex`, it is aware of the language. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/Russian-Phd-LaTeX-Dissertation-Template/tree/master/BibTeX-Styles